# Strategy for cleaning up historical commits of SECRETS detected by GGSHIELD

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, continuous-integration

I am quite new to CIDI type of systems. I have been playing around with GITHUB and more recently with GITGUARDIAN using just test code and private repository. I have executed GGSHIELD to detect any secrets in my repository and it came up with a lot being from historical commits. I love to know the best approach to clean up historical commits of SECRETS. The only approach I can think of is delete the repository entirely and recreate it with a clean code base. Any advise will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is the repository public or private? Are the secrets still secret (e.g. passwords no longer in use won't help anyone)?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the nature of the project.

If it is a private project that no one else has access to, then you have the option of rewriting the history by use of `git rebase`. Using interactive mode you can rewrite your history to remove the commits containing the secrets. Here is a pretty good resource for that process. https://blog.gitguardian.com/rewriting-git-history-cheatsheet/

If this is public code or is already shared with others, then rewriting history is going to be a lot more complex, as everyone else would need to also accept your new rewritten history as well. Assuming you have rotated those credentials or they were never valid, the question then becomes "is it acceptable to have these invalid secrets in my history?" If absolutely not, then perhaps nuking the project and starting over from just the current commit is a viable option.

Before you delete/recreate the repo, it is important to think through what was exposed, what actions might be needed to remedy any leaks, and how to prevent hardcoding secrets in the future.

If any are still valid, it is important to rotate those ASAP. Follow the guidance of the API or service on how to do that effectively.

There are many paths to excluding secrets from a codebase. I like a vault solutions (like Hashicorp's Vault for free or Doppler), but I also use `.env` files located outside the project directory for smaller one-off projects. There are a lot of articles on this subject out there.